# "Undefined Reference Error" in Tizen Native Application

Tags: c++, tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to add a background image on a form in Tizen platform. I have following two classes:

first class:

```
class BaseForm1
: public Tizen::Ui::Controls::Form
, public Tizen::Ui::IActionEventListener
, public Tizen::Ui::Controls::IFormBackEventListener
{
public:
BaseForm1();
virtual ~BaseForm1();

    virtual bool Initialize(void) = 0;
    virtual result OnInitializing(void);
    bool SetFooter(void);
    virtual void OnActionPerformed(const Tizen::Ui::Control& source, int actionId);
    virtual void OnFormBackRequested(Tizen::Ui::Controls::Form& source) ;

protected:
    static const int ID_EXIT = 100;
};
```

second class:

```
class CreateForm1:
public BaseForm1,
public Tizen::Ui::IItemEventListener

{

protected:


public:
CreateForm1();
virtual ~CreateForm1();
virtual bool Initialize(void);
virtual result OnInitializing(void);
virtual void OnActionPerformed(const Tizen::Ui::Control& source, int actionId);
virtual void OnItemStateChanged(const Tizen::Ui::Control& source, int index, int itemId, Tizen::Ui::ItemStatus status);
virtual result OnDraw(void);
};
```

In the second class I use `BaseForm1::OnInitializing()` method in `OnInitializing(void)` method. Second class inherits first class (`BaseForm1`). I used `OnDraw()` method to draw a background image.

But this error is shown:

```
./src/CreateForm1.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x4c): undefined reference to `CreateForm1::OnDraw()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
clang++: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see    invocation)
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919495/how-to-set-background-image-in-tizen-native-app) is helpful, but my code is not working. Your valuable answers will be helpful.

Comment: Did you actually implement `CreateForm1::OnDraw` somewhere?

Comment: Thank you.I examined my code and found that I misspelled the name of class. Now it is working.